# Update a row with the position mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm am currently writing a little ranking system in a database. The main problem in the site is that the SQL querys are limited, that's why I try to write the smaller amount of querys, even if that's mean more complicated querys. At the moment my table ranking contain 3 field, user_id, score and rank. Obviously a better score mean a highter rank, here is a little [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3db48a/1) of my data.

```
CREATE TABLE ranking(user_id INT, score INT, rank INT);
INSERT INTO ranking(user_id, score, rank) VALUES 
    (1, 150, 1), 
    (2, 120, 3), 
    (3, 130, 2), 
    (4, 100, 5), 
    (5, 110, 4);
```

My aim is to write a query that change the score (from here no problem), then set the ranking to the new position, in my fiddle, if I want to add 15 to the score of the user 4, his score will be 115, so he will have a better score that user 5, and his ranking should now be 4 and user five ranking's should be 5, is it possible to do such thing using pure SQL and in only one (maybe two) querys?  I have no idea of how to build such complex query

Edit: After some research, I found some querys With `SET @rn=0;
SELECT @rn:=@rn+1 AS rankid`, But how use this in a subquery to update the ranking of every user affected by the score change?

Comment: Instead of inserting the ranking manually on creation, why wouldn't you rank them upon future selection?  That way it will always account for any updated values.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff It's a good idea, but the fact is that I will often have to check if user x has rank y, and only this user, so IMO it's more easy to check the rank in the database than re-generate the whole ranking each time I want to check the rank of a specific user. But your idea is still good and I'll use it if I see the answer to my problem is too complex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE ranking AS r1
JOIN (SELECT score AS old_score, score+15 AS new_score FROM ranking WHERE user_id = 4) AS r2
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS new_rank FROM ranking 
      WHERE user_id != 4 
      AND score > (SELECT score+15 FROM ranking WHERE user_id = 4)) r3
SET r1.score = IF(r1.user_id = 4, r2.new_score, r1.score),
    r1.rank = CASE WHEN r1.user_id = 4 THEN r3.new_rank
                   WHEN (r1.score > r2.old_score) = (r1.score > r2.new_score) THEN r1.rank
                   WHEN r1.score > r2.old_score AND r1.score <= r2.new_score THEN r1.rank + 1
              END
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5d05d/1)